# Converting Byte[4] to float - Integer[4] array works but byte[4] does not

Tags: java, floating-point

This is probably a basic question for out more experienced programmers out there. I'm a bit of a noob and can't work this one out. I'm trying to unpack a binary file and the doco is not too clear on how floats are stored. I have found a routine that does this, but it will only work if I pass an integer array of the bytes. The  correct answer is -1865.0. I need to be able to pass the byte array and get the correct answer. How do I need to change the code to make *float4byte* return -1865.0. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] bytes = {(byte) 0xC3,(byte) 0X74,(byte) 0X90,(byte) 0X00 };
        int[] ints = {(int) 0xC3,(int) 0X74,(int) 0X90,(int) 0X00 };

        // This give the wrong answer
        float f = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getFloat();
        System.out.println("VAL ByteBuffer BI: " + f);

        // This give the wrong answer
        f = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getFloat();
        System.out.println("VAL ByteBuffer LI: " + f);

        //This gives the RIGHT answer
        f = float4int (ints[0], ints[1], ints[2], ints[3]);
        System.out.println("VAL Integer : " + f);

        // This gives the wrong answer
        f = float4byte (bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);
        System.out.println("VAL Bytes : " + f);

    }
    private static float float4int(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {

        int sgn, mant, exp;
        System.out.println ("IN Int: "+String.format("%02X ", a)+
                String.format("%02X ", b)+String.format("%02X ", c)+String.format("%02X ", d));

        mant = b << 16 | c << 8 | d;
        if (mant == 0) return 0.0f;

        sgn = -(((a & 128) >> 6) - 1);
        exp = (a & 127) - 64;

        return (float) (sgn * Math.pow(16.0, exp - 6) * mant);
    }

    private static float float4byte(byte a, byte b, byte c, byte d)
    {

        int sgn, mant, exp;
        System.out.println ("IN Byte : "+String.format("%02X ", a)+
                String.format("%02X ", b)+String.format("%02X ", c)+String.format("%02X ", d));

        mant = b << 16 | c << 8 | d;
        if (mant == 0) return 0.0f;

        sgn = -(((a & 128) >> 6) - 1);
        exp = (a & 127) - 64;

        return (float) (sgn * Math.pow(16.0, exp - 6) * mant);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your solution with ByteBuffer doesn't work: the bytes do not match the (Java) internal representation of the float value.

The Java representation is

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(Float.floatToIntBits(-1865.0f)));
```

which gives `c4e92000`

Comment: +1, though strictly speaking, it's not necessarily true that that's "the (Java) internal representation". `Float.floatToIntBits` is specified to use the IEEE 754 single-precision (binary32) representation, whereas Java implementations are only required to use the same value set for their `float`-s (not necessarily the same representation of each value).

Answer (score 1):

`byte`s are signed in Java. When calculating the mantissa `mant`, the bytes are implicitly converted from `byte`s to `int`s - with the sign "extended", i.e. `(byte)0x90` (decimal -112) gets converted `0xFFFFFF90` (32 bits int). However what you want is just the original bytes' 8 bits (`0x00000090`).

In order to compensate for the effect of sign extension, it suffices to change one line:

```
mant = (b & 0xFF) << 16 | (c & 0xFF) << 8 | (d & 0xFF)
```

Here, in `(c & 0xFF)`, the 1-bits caused by sign extension are stripped after (implicit) conversion to `int`.

---

Edit:

The repacking of floats could be done via the IEEE 754 representation which can be obtained by `Float.floatToIntBits` (which avoids using slow logarithms). Some complexity in the code is caused by the change of base from 2 to 16:

```
private static byte[] byte4float(float f) {
    assert !Float.isNaN(f);
    // see also JavaDoc of Float.intBitsToFloat(int)
    int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(f);
    int s = (bits >> 31) == 0 ? 1 : -1;
    int e = (bits >> 23) & 0xFF;
    int m = (e == 0) ? (bits & 0x7FFFFF) << 1 : (bits&  0x7FFFFF) | 0x800000;

    int exp = (e - 150) / 4 + 6;
    int mant;
    int mantissaShift = (e - 150) % 4;  // compensate for base 16
    if (mantissaShift >= 0) mant = m << mantissaShift;
    else { mant = m << (mantissaShift + 4); exp--;  }
    if (mant > 0xFFFFFFF) { mant >>= 4; exp++; }  // loose of precision
    byte a = (byte) ((1 - s) << 6 | (exp + 64));
    return new byte[]{ a, (byte) (mant >> 16), (byte) (mant >> 8), (byte) mant };
}
```

The code does not take into account any rules that may exist for the packaging, e.g. for representing zero or normalization of the mantissa. But it might serve as a starting point.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. Problem solved. Thanks. I am going to need to reverse the process and repack floats in the same way. Not sure I know how. Any tips on how to do that would also be appreciated.

Comment: @Andrew L: Added an example implementation for the reverse function `byte4float`. See edit.

Comment: Thanks @halfbit. What I have discovered is that I am working with the old IBM 370 mainframe float. See [IBM_Floating_Point_Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Floating_Point_Architecture#IEEE_754_on_IBM_mainframes). This solution did not quite work, but something to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @halfbit and a bit of testing and minor changes, this routine appears convert IEEE 754 float into IBM float.

```
public static byte[] byte4float(float f) {
    assert !Float.isNaN(f);
    // see also JavaDoc of Float.intBitsToFloat(int)

    int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(f);
    int s = (bits >> 31) == 0 ? 1 : -1;
    int e = (bits >> 23) & 0xFF;
    int m = (e == 0) ? (bits & 0x7FFFFF) << 1 : (bits&  0x7FFFFF) | 0x800000;

    int exp = (e - 150) / 4 + 6;
    int mant;
    int mantissaShift = (e - 150) % 4;  // compensate for base 16
    if (mantissaShift >= 0) mant = m >> mantissaShift;
    else mant = m >> (Math.abs(mantissaShift));
    if (mant > 0xFFFFFFF) { mant >>= 4; exp++; }  // loose of precision */
    byte a = (byte) ((1 - s) << 6 | (exp + 64));
    return new byte[]{ a, (byte) (mant >> 16), (byte) (mant >> 8), (byte) mant };
}
```

I think this is right and appears to be working.